# Use ST_ApproximateMedialAxis with 3D geometries

Tags: postgis, sfcgal

It is written in [docs](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_ApproximateMedialAxis.html) that `ST_ApproximateMedialAxis` doesn't drop z-index or third coordinate, but in practice it **does** drop z-index and returns 2D geometry.

I pass 3D geometry into `ST_ApproximateMedialAxis` and expect to get 3D geometry as a result.

What I tried:

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_ApproximateMedialAxis(ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((0 0 10, 0 50 10, 10 50 10, 10 0 10, 0 0 10))')))

+-----------------------------+
| st_astext                   |
|-----------------------------|
| MULTILINESTRING((5 5,5 45)) |
+-----------------------------+


SELECT ST_AsText(ST_ApproximateMedialAxis(ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON Z ((0 0 10, 0 50 10, 10 50 10, 10 0 10, 0 0 10))')))

+-----------------------------+
| st_astext                   |
|-----------------------------|
| MULTILINESTRING((5 5,5 45)) |
+-----------------------------+


SELECT ST_AsEWKT(ST_ApproximateMedialAxis(GeomFromEWKT('POLYGON((0 0 10, 0 50 10, 10 50 10, 10 0 10, 0 0 10))')))

+-----------------------------+
| st_asewkt                   |
|-----------------------------|
| MULTILINESTRING((5 5,5 45)) |
+-----------------------------+


SELECT ST_AsEWKT(ST_ApproximateMedialAxis(GeomFromEWKT('POLYGON Z((0 0 10, 0 50 10, 10 50 10, 10 0 10, 0 0 10))')))

+-----------------------------+
| st_asewkt                   |
|-----------------------------|
| MULTILINESTRING((5 5,5 45)) |
+-----------------------------+
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think you are correct, I get the same answers, and looking at the [source code](https://github.com/Oslandia/SFCGAL/blob/e098b6b30c4ff5e5478b6132be5fcd1fa2b14731/test/unit/SFCGAL/algorithm/ApproximateMedialAxis.cpp) I see no evidence of 3D versions of this function. It is possibly worth asking on Postgis mail group or irc.

Comment: @JohnPowell indeed, [`straightSkeleton`](https://github.com/Oslandia/SFCGAL/blob/e098b6b30c4ff5e5478b6132be5fcd1fa2b14731/src/algorithm/straightSkeleton.cpp) transforms to and validates 2D polygons only.

Comment: @ThingumaBob. Which implies that the docs are wrong, no?

Comment: One possible solution to this would be to rotate your polygon so that it is on the x-y plane, calcuate the medial axis or straight skeleton, add a default z coordinate, with ST_Force3D, and then do the inverse rotation. As the polygons should be planar, this ought  to give the correct result. In your case, as the z coordinates are always 10, you simply need to do `SELECT ST_Translate(ST_Force3D(ST_ApproximateMedialAxis(geom)), 0, 0, 10)`;

Comment: @JohnPowell I'd say so, yes. I just had that with another function (could safely run with 3D coordinates but Z index is dropped) but can't remember which one...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, looking at the source code for the [ST_ApproximateMedialAxis](https://github.com/Oslandia/SFCGAL/blob/e098b6b30c4ff5e5478b6132be5fcd1fa2b14731/test/unit/SFCGAL/algorithm/ApproximateMedialAxis.cpp) and [ST_StraightSkeleton](https://github.com/Oslandia/SFCGAL/blob/e098b6b30c4ff5e5478b6132be5fcd1fa2b14731/src/algorithm/straightSkeleton.cpp) indicates that both do in fact drop the z-axis, ie, they work, but ignore the z values.

However, there is a workaround. If you consider that a medial axis is a LineString calculated from a planar polygon, all you need to do is rotate your POLYGONZ so that it lies in the x/y plane, calculute the medial axis and then do the inverse rotation. There is a function, [ST_Affine](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Affine.html) that allows for simultaneous rotations and translations, though you need to calculate all the parameters.

The equation for the plane is:

> > Ax + By + Cz + D = 0

which can be found by using a [cross product](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2140132/finding-plane-equation-given-two-lines)
and once you have that, you can plug these numbers into the equation found in this answer from [Math Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1167717/transform-a-plane-to-the-xy-plane), which will allow you to translate and rotate the polygon so it lies in the x/y plane. The equations are pretty hideous to look at, but are basically just plug and play.

Once you have calculated the coefficients for rotation and translation, a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, xoff, yoff, zoff, you problem can be reduced to:

```
 SELECT 
     ST_Translate(-xoff, -yoff, -zoff(
        ST_Affine(a, d, g, b, e, h, c, f, i, 0, 0, 0,
           ST_Force3D(
              ST_ApproximateMedialAxis(
                 ST_Translate(xoff, yoff, zoff(
                    ST_Affine(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, 0, 0, 0, geom)
                 )
              )
           )
       )
 );
```

Note, you need the use [ST_Force3D](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Force_3D.html) in order to add a z coordinate to the geometry representing the medial axis in the x/y plane -- this will  default to 0, but get its correct value once the geometry is rotated and translated back to its original location. To reverse the transfrom, you need to do the inverse of the rotation, which conveniently is the transpose of the rotation matrix, and then do the reverse translation.

I leave it to you to calculate a, b, c, xoff, etc :D.

In your case, as the polygon has z = 10 in all cases, you could just run:

```
SELECT 
  ST_AsText( 
        ST_Translate(
              ST_Force3D(
                 ST_ApproximateMedialAxis(
                     ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((0 0 10, 0 50 10, 10 50 10, 10 0 10, 0 0 10))')
                )
             )
       ,0,0,10)
   );
```

which gives:

> MULTILINESTRING Z ((5 5 10,5 45 10))

Comment: Thank you John! It sounds reasonable. Will check it out!

Comment: No problem, sorry for being lazy, I couldn't be bothered to actually calculate the plane and rotation matrices :-) Quite a few 3D problems can actually be reduced to 2D problems via projections, rotations and the like.

Comment: +1, but I guess this is getting ridiculously intense for arbitrary polygons ,) one thing to the links: the *SFCGAL* `approximateMedialAxis` wraps around *CGAL*'s `Straight_skeleton_2` function, with some extra dangle removal. you are linking the automated unit test there. and cascading through the functions (e.g. [here](https://svn.osgeo.org/postgis/branches/2.5/liblwgeom/) and [here](https://svn.osgeo.org/postgis/branches/2.5/postgis/)) it is quite obvious that the docs might need to get changed...

Comment: @ThingumaBob. Lol. I have no control over the docs. Ridiculously intense, you say, would you like to write a plpgsql function that will rotate an arbitrary planar PolygonZ onto the x/y plane, thereby rendering it somewhat less intense :D.

Comment: @JohnPowell wait, the docs part was decoupled from the rest of the comment; more an *'btw.'*, since we talked about the docs above. yeah, I was imagining some pretty weird polygons and what you'd have to do to get them projected onto the [x, y] plane...and surrendered to it ,)

Comment: Andrey, sorry, I forgot to to reverse a translation and a rotation, you have to separate them, and, the reverse rotation matrix is just the transpose. So, I have now separated this in the answer.